# Spring 3.1.x milestone repository

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am currently searching for a maven repository that contains the recent spring milestones of version 3.1.x.

There are a lot of links when searching google, but they all seem to be dead.

Does anyone know the link to the repository?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the repo:

```
<repository>
    <id>repository.springframework.milestone</id>
    <name>Spring Framework Maven Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>
```

**Source:** http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=92277

Hint: you can't browse this repo, as it's in an Amazon Cloud. But it is there :-)

Comment: You can browse it, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

http://maven.springframework.org/milestone

You can browse the S3 backed repo with Shrub
http://shrub.appspot.com/maven.springframework.org/